# SSL details of installation, connection & authorization for iphone

Tags: iphone, ssl, https

I don't have SSL on server side i am using microsoft IIS Server. I want to make the access secured with Https & SSL with my iphone application can anyone send me the details what to do & what are the requirements. I am new in both iphone & SSL

Comment: Are you using a particular HTTP library?

Comment: No, just simple soap request. I want to make it HTTPS because of the security perspective